# Model name mapping with Open API Code generator

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator, spring-hateoas

I am using Open API Code generator to generate SDK for my APIs. https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/

My response POJO was as follows.

```java
class User {
    String name;
    String id;
    List<Account> accounts;
}
```

I have integrated Spring Hateoas to support HAL Links to Account. My class structure now is

```java
class User {
    String name;
    String id;
    List<EntityModel<Account>> accounts;
}
```

Due to this change, the generated SDK changed the name of the class from List in the SDK to List which results in breaking change.

Is there anyway, I can specify SDK generator to continue using `Account`, instead of the new name `EntityModelAccount`